# Use QT 4.7.4 Window to show a video with libvlc 2.1.0

Tags: c++, qt, vlc

i tried the whole day to show a video with VLC in my QT Project.

The video works if i dont use the line `libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd`. Without this line VLC generates a window automatically. It is very important then i can choose my own window or subwindow area to show the video.

The error is:
`main vout display error: Failed to set on top`

I used different QT classes to show the video. QVideoWidget, QWidget, QFrame and QMainWindow. It didnt change anything. (OS is windows)

There are a lot of different solutions in the internet. I guess it should work with the code below.

I also tried different versions of libvlc, but the error was always the same.

play() method:

```
void MainWindow::play()
{

    libvlc_instance_t * inst;
    libvlc_media_player_t *mp;
    libvlc_media_t *m;

    /* Load the VLC engine */
    inst = libvlc_new (0, NULL);

    if(!inst)
        std::cout << "Can't load video player plugins" << std::endl;


    m = libvlc_media_new_path (inst, "content.avi");

    /* Create a media player playing environment */
    mp = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media (m);

    HWND windowID = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(this->winId());

    /* It works without this line */
    libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd(mp, windowID);


    /* play the media_player */
    libvlc_media_player_play (mp);

    Sleep(uint(10000)); /* Let it play a bit */

    /* Stop playing */
    libvlc_media_player_stop (mp);

    /* Free the media_player */
    libvlc_media_player_release (mp);

    libvlc_release (inst);

}
```

main.cpp:

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
MainWindow w;
w.show();

w.play();

return a.exec();
```

Thanks in advance for helpful informations.

Darian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Thanks for your advices. Both tips from you are working fine at my application.
My bug was the line
Sleep(uint(10000));

I think if I don't use libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd, VLC will create its own event-loop.
But in the case I set HWND, I naturally have to use my own event-loop.
Because of the sleep and the subsequent stop and release, VLC is finished before the Qt event-loop starts.

Shift these lines in other methods and reasonable use solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this line to tell where video should play. It is working for me. videoWidget is just regular QWidget nothing else.

```
libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd(m_player, (void*)ui->videoWidget->winId());
```

So try this:

```
libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd(mp, (void*)this->winId());
```

**Edit: Added Working example**

Works on Mac and Windows with Qt 4.8.1 tested also Qt 5.1.1, VLC SDK is 2.2.0-git-20130728-0003

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QDebug>
#include <vlc/vlc.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QMainWindow *window = new QMainWindow;
    QWidget *videoWidget = new QWidget;
    window->setCentralWidget(videoWidget);

    libvlc_media_player_t *m_player;
    libvlc_media_t *m_media;
    libvlc_instance_t *m_vlc;

    // load the vlc engine
    m_vlc = libvlc_new(0, NULL);

    // open media
    m_media = libvlc_media_new_path(m_vlc, "test.mp4");

    if (m_media == 0) {
        qDebug() << "not possible to open file";
        return 0;
    }

    m_player = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(m_media);

    // no need to keep the media now
    libvlc_media_release(m_media);

#if defined(Q_OS_WIN) // Windows
    libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd(m_player, (void*)videoWidget->winId());
#elif defined(Q_OS_MAC) // Mac
    libvlc_media_player_set_nsobject(m_player, (void *)videoWidget->winId());
#else //Linux
    int windid = _videoWidget->winId();
    libvlc_media_player_set_xwindow (m_player, windid );
#endif

    libvlc_media_player_play(m_player);

    window->show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

But unfortunately output window shows your error:

```
main vout display error: Failed to set on top
```

But everything works as expected.

Comment: Sorry but with this code i have the same error. Which libvlc and qt version do you use?

Comment: I have edited my answer. I have added working example and answer to your question in comment.

Answer (score 0):

I use QFrame and libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd (player, reinterpret_cast (winId)); 
But I crate player via libvlc_media_player_new and then set media to it. Try to do the same?